# Can Gmail be configured automatically to print all received email attachments?

Tags: gmail, printing

Looking for a way to automate my Gmail so that it will automatically print all the email attachments that I receive. I've read about a service called IFTTT, but I don't believe it can be used successfully in this situation.

Is that possible?

I know that this can be achieved in Outlook using a set of rules or a macro, but can I do this with the web app of Gmail?

Did any of you guys manage to automate this function with Gmail?

Answer (score 3):

It's the *client* that prints email, not Gmail itself. Though your *browser*, used to view email on the Gmail site, may not offer this feature, another client can do this. For example, if Gmail were to be read using the Mozilla *Thunderbird* email client, then [that client can be configured](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1157054) to print any queue, including the Inbox. For *Thunderbird*, you'd need the free [FiltaQuilla](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/filtaquilla/) add-on. If you want to automatically print attachments, as well, you might need another add-on, e.g., [Printing Tools](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/printingtools/).

There are numerous [alternatives to *Thunderbird*](https://alternativeto.net/software/mozilla-thunderbird), as well.

Having said all that, I would not want to print *every* email attachment. Some might be hundreds of pages, or contain malware. It's safer, if longer, to download, let the AV scan the attachment, and *then* print it.

Answer (score 0):

I use Automatic email manager.  You can set different email account to download new emails from 1 minute to hours later.  It will also sent the atached file to a folder on you computer

Answer (score -1):

You could give [File Processor](http://www.fileprocessor.info) a try. But make sure the interval to check gmail is > 10 minutes as google adds limitations to protect its services.